# Buildout is it possible to override dependencies for an application containing its own dependencies?

Tags: python, django, dependency-management, buildout

Is it possible to override dependencies in buildout for an egg?
I need to add some newer libraries to some eggs which contain requirements for older packages.

Comment: what do you mean ? you just need it for your local installation ? Actually, I reread five times your sentence, and each time I understand something different, could you detail what you have in mind ? :)

Comment: I have an egg in buildout which has some dependencies to for example south = 0.7.3. I need to use south 0.7.6 so is it possible to override that dependency in buildout.cfg file?

Comment: Don't set hard dependencies in your eggs like that. *At most* set a lower limit for a version.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the buildout.cfg and add a version section with all the dependencies you need :

```
[buildout]
...
versions = versions

[versions]
south = 0.7.3
```

You can also Look at the following documentations for more :

- http://packages.python.org/buildout-versions/use.html
- http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2010/08/fake-version-pinning

Comment: and as a side note, if you do upgrade your code's dependencies and need specific version pinning, don't forget to update setup.py's install_requires, because that's using setup.py you'll create your egg and declare dependencies.